# Is there a compiler flag for Visual C++ to check for type safety for calls to printf()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I have read there are a few flags in gcc to do catch some of the type violations for calls to printf, I haven't been able to find if there are similar ways to achieve this in Visual C++'s compiler (any version of VC++, from 2005 onward).

Comment: -Wall may be what you are looking at

Comment: @Chubsdad, -Wall doesn't catch it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, VC++ doesn't have it. MS appears to have done almost no new development specifically for the C compiler for years now -- almost the only updates have been mostly accidental side-effects of updates to the C++ compiler. Since this would see little use in C++ it hasn't happened, and I wouldn't expect it to happen any time soon either.